# AWS -create tag when lunching instance - php SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I'm launching an AWS instance using the PHP SDK and everything works well except I'm not able to set the name(tag) of that instance.
Here is my code:

```
$result_create_instance = $ec2_client->runInstances([
     'AdditionalInfo'    =>  'notihng',
     'ImageId'           =>  $aws_ami, // REQUIRED
     'MaxCount'          =>  1, // REQUIRED
     'MinCount'          =>  1, // REQUIRED
     'InstanceType'      =>  $aws_instance_type,
     'Monitoring'        =>  [
                                'Enabled' => true // REQUIRED
                            ],
     'UserData'          =>  $user_Data,
     'SubnetId'          =>  'subnet-125cxxxx',
     'SecurityGroupIds'  => ['sg-5axxxxx'],
     'TagSpecification`  =>  [
                                'ResourceType'  => 'instance',
                                'Tags'          =>   [  'Key' => 'Name',
                                                        'Value'=>'my instance'
                                                        ],
                            ],

]);
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be `TagSpecifications` with an `s` not `TagSpecification`. Also make sure you are using a recent version of the AWS SDK since adding tags at launch is a fairly new feature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used TagSpecifications but with no luck, i will try to update the sdk and see it that solves.